# Make an element with border, «stiched» to the outer borders of objects inside

Tags: html, css

What is the way to make a div(or another element) with border, «stiched» to the outer borders of objects inside that div?

For example: [image: example]

Comment: I don't think that there is a direct way.

Comment: Does those elements always have the same positions? Do you change them dynamically (like add/remove some block depending on some condition)

Comment: Well, the positions can change and some elements may be added/deleted. I'd like to align the elements inside the div so, they can even overflow some elements. But the border is more important.

Comment: There is a variant, but it doesn't suit me well: http://jsfiddle.net/sSMT4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it only with css and without any javascript plugin, you could do it with a lot of work, like following for example : 
[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GcWGh/3/)

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="red"><div class="content">Red</div></div>
    <div class="green"><div class="content">Green</div></div>
    <div class="blue"><div class="content">Blue</div></div>
    <div class="black"><div class="content">Black</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main {position:relative;}
.black, .red, .blue, .green {
    position:absolute;
    border:3px dotted #000;
    background:#FFF;
    z-index:10;
}
.content {position:relative;margin:10px;}
.black {top:300px;left:103px;z-index:9;}
.black .content {height:180px;width:280px;background:#000;}
.blue{ top:50px;left:200px;border-bottom:none;}
.blue .content {height:30px;width:30px;background:#009;}
.red{top:0px;left:0px;}
.red .content {height:280px;width:80px;background:#F00;}
.green{top:100px;left:103px;border-left:none;border-bottom:none;}
.green .content{height:180px;width:180px;background:#070;}
```

​
​Here you need to set the position of each element and their sizes, then you have to adjust for each the display of each superimposed border.

It's a little bit ugly, but that's working...

Comment: I'm working on it, I didn't found a plugin to do it, so I try to make it by myself. I'll tell you when my script will be created.

Comment: But there is a lot of problems. It wont be possible, if you don't set a fixed height and width to the elements. Because the element will superimpose other... It shouldn't be possible to organize them correctly in HTML. So : have you got an example of the html/css presentation ? then I could make something to help you

Comment: Let's think that all the objects are images with fixed width/height. The objects will be the thumbnails of photos, so it's not the problem.

Comment: Ok ! And what's about their positions relative, float, absolute ?

Comment: I've tried to make some presentation: http://jsfiddle.net/CHcML/ . Relative suits well for this, i think.

Comment: Yes, no need of javascript/jquery plugin. (I was going crazy with it...). Everything can be donne in CSS like I showed you. The only thing you have to do, is to `border-left/top : none;` and more `z-index:+1` to superimpose the border of other element.

Comment: There is a problem - when red's bottom border is lower, than black's top border, then we see black's left border upper piece, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/SNjQP/

Comment: It's not black border but red border, BTW you have to adjust everything for you needs, like the margin-bottom of the .green .content for example, and play with the z-index too.